# Move an image over a canvas in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-store-apps

I need to move an image over a canvas on tap and slide. How can I achieve this. I tried the following. The image is moving but not as the user moves it.

XAML

```
<Canvas Background="White">
     <Image Name="img" Width="200" Height="200" Source="Assets/11.png" ManipulationMode="All"  ManipulationStarted="img_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="img_ManipulationDelta"/>
</Canvas>
```

C#

```
private Point initialPt;
private void img_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    initialPt = e.Position;
}

private void img_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Point currentPt = e.Position;
    double x = currentPt.X - initialPt.X;
    double y = currentPt.Y - initialPt.Y;
    if (x != 0 || y != 0)
    {
        TranslateTransform posTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        posTransform.X = currentPt.X;
        posTransform.Y = currentPt.Y;
        img.RenderTransform = posTransform;
        e.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.Position` is relative to the Image control, but you want the movement to be calculated relative to the Canvas. You should attach the event handlers to the Canvas instead of the Image.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/17/Building-A-Multi-Touch-Photo-Viewer-Control) for moving and zooming an image. It's old but should still work

Comment: The below question will give a more accurate way to do this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942691/c-sharp-dragging-images-inside-canvas-in-windows-store-app-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `TranslateTransform`, you should directly set the absolute position in the canvas, so you have to bind the `ManipulationDelta` event to the Canvas, and detect if the point of impact is inside of the image.

```
<Canvas Background="White" ManipulationMode="All"  ManipulationDelta="canvas_ManipulationDelta">
     <Image Name="img" Width="200" Height="200" Source="Assets/11.png"/>
</Canvas>
```

Here is the new event handling function:

```
   private void canvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        if ((e.Position.X > Canvas.GetLeft(img) && e.Position.X < Canvas.GetLeft(img) + img.Width) 
           || (e.Position.Y > Canvas.GetTop(img) && e.Position.Y < Canvas.GetTop(img) + img.Height)) {        
        { 
             Canvas.SetLeft(img, e.Position.X);
             Canvas.SetTop(img, e.Position.Y);
        }
   }
```

Simple as pie. You can remove `initialPt` and `img_ManipulationStarted`.

Comment: Sure, but `e.Position` is relative to the Image, not the Canvas. So it's not *that* simple. OP also has to move the event handlers from the Image to the Canvas.

Comment: Uh, I had forgot this part. Edited